# How to handle unhandled exception in .NET web services

Tags: .net, web-services, exception

I need to handle all the exceptions globally in .NET 2.0 web service (ASMX), i tried using Application_Error event in global.asax, but it's not fired in web services case, it works fine for web based applications.

Any suggestions???

Comment: asmx (2.0-style) or svc (WCF)?